# How to INSERT time in SQL Server using data type time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing the query to insert data to the table but I keep getting an error:

> Incorrect Syntax near ':'`

This is the query that create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Consultation_Slot
(
     Slot_ID CHAR(7) NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
     Appointment_Purpose VARCHAR(255) NULL,
     Appointment_Status VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
     Cancellation_Reason VARCHAR(255) NULL,
     Slot_Time time(7) NOT NULL,
     Slot_Date DATE NOT NULL,
     Slot_Day CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     Room_No VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     Lecturer_ID CHAR(3) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Lecturer(Lecturer_ID),
     Student_ID CHAR(6) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Student(Student_ID),
     Schedule_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Weekly_Consultation_Schedule(Schedule_ID)
)
```

This is the `INSERT` statement that I tried to execute:

```
INSERT INTO Consultation_Slot 
VALUES (1000000,'I need to learn maths','avaliable','', 13:30, 1-28-2018, 
        'Sunday', 'RN001', 1111, 880001, 30001);
GO
```

Comment: You need to treat dates and times as strings (so `'13:30'`). You shouldn't use regional formats for dates; try `'20180128'`. Also, this shouldn't be tagged `mysql`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to surround the `DATE` and `TIME` values with apostrophes:

```
INSERT INTO Consultation_Slot VALUES
       (1000000,'I need to learn maths','avaliable','', '13:30', '1-28-2018',
        'Sunday', 'RN001', 1111, 880001, 30001);
```

Only number type values don't need apostrophes.

It is also recommended to surround all the other values in your queries with apostrophes. It's true that they are numbers, but the column types are string based, so providing the values as number will cause unnecessary implicit casting:

```
INSERT INTO Consultation_Slot VALUES
       ('1000000','I need to learn maths','avaliable','', '13:30', '1-28-2018',
        'Sunday', 'RN001', '1111', '880001', '30001');
```

However, it seems that your table design is incorrect, and some of those columns should be numbers not string, so review your table design.

Comment: Is it the ID should be integer? yea i just changed it

Comment: Not necessarily, IDs can be any type, but more commonly integers. Integers perform better than other types, so only use other types when it is really necessary. For example, if you're creating an app for students, and the ID on the student card contains characters.